# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR when exporting kable to image (Rstudio + Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: r, ubuntu, kable, kableextra, rstudio-server

I'm trying to export table made with kableExtra in R. It looks ok in the R Studio environment but if I try to export it it gives me this error:

```
> kable(csv) %>%                                                          
+     kable_styling("striped", full_width = F, htmltable_class = 'Liberation Sans') %>%
+     kable_minimal() %>%
+     save_kable(file = paste0(outdir, name, '.png'), bs_theme = "flatly",
+                zoom = 1.5)
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-cesarkero'
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.
TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.
Error in magick_image_trim(image, fuzz) : 
  rsession: geometry does not contain image `/home/cesarkero/HDD/D4/GoogleDrive/Proyectos/Master_UNED/01_Materias/06_EE/07_Trabajo/03_Resultados/04_CONSOLIDADOS/07a.png' @ warning/attribute.c/GetImageBoundingBox/247
```

The file is exported but totally empty.

Here is the file used as csv object: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fmplGNKB7MSKvXpNI_YrThE1F2EKszTf/view?usp=sharing

---

**Update 19/04/2022**

If I try this I get a similar error:

```
> webshot::install_phantomjs()
Error: invalid version specification ‘QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-cesarkero'’
```

I had already installed phantomjs in linux terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y phantomjs
```

Here is my sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] landtools_0.1.0       lubridate_1.8.0       plyr_1.8.6           
 [4] data.table_1.14.2     raster_3.5-15         rgeos_0.5-9          
 [7] rgdal_1.5-28          sp_1.4-6              exifr_0.3.2          
[10] nngeo_0.4.5           spatstat_2.3-3        spatstat.linnet_2.3-2
[13] spatstat.core_2.4-0   rpart_4.1.16          nlme_3.1-157         
[16] spatstat.random_2.1-0 spatstat.geom_2.3-2   spatstat.data_2.1-2  
[19] purrr_0.3.4           readODS_1.7.0         stringr_1.4.0        
[22] mapview_2.10.0        dplyr_1.0.8           readr_2.1.2          
[25] sf_1.0-7              magrittr_2.0.3        magick_2.7.3         
[28] kableExtra_1.3.4     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] spatstat.sparse_2.1-0 satellite_1.0.4       webshot_0.5.2        
 [4] httr_1.4.2            tools_4.1.3           utf8_1.2.2           
 [7] R6_2.5.1              KernSmooth_2.23-20    DBI_1.1.2            
[10] mgcv_1.8-40           colorspace_2.0-3      processx_3.5.2       
[13] tidyselect_1.1.2      leaflet_2.1.0         compiler_4.1.3       
[16] leafem_0.1.6          cli_3.2.0             rvest_1.0.2          
[19] xml2_1.3.3            scales_1.1.1          classInt_0.4-3       
[22] callr_3.7.0           proxy_0.4-26          rappdirs_0.3.3       
[25] goftest_1.2-3         systemfonts_1.0.4     digest_0.6.29        
[28] foreign_0.8-82        spatstat.utils_2.3-0  rmarkdown_2.13       
[31] svglite_2.1.0         base64enc_0.1-3       pkgconfig_2.0.3      
[34] htmltools_0.5.2       fastmap_1.1.0         htmlwidgets_1.5.4    
[37] rlang_1.0.2           rstudioapi_0.13       generics_0.1.2       
[40] crosstalk_1.2.0       Matrix_1.4-1          Rcpp_1.0.8.2         
[43] munsell_0.5.0         fansi_1.0.3           abind_1.4-5          
[46] lifecycle_1.0.1       terra_1.5-21          stringi_1.7.6        
[49] maptools_1.1-3        grid_4.1.3            crayon_1.5.1         
[52] deldir_1.0-6          lattice_0.20-45       splines_4.1.3        
[55] tensor_1.5            hms_1.1.1             ps_1.6.0             
[58] knitr_1.37            pillar_1.7.0          codetools_0.2-18     
[61] stats4_4.1.3          glue_1.6.2            evaluate_0.15        
[64] png_0.1-7             vctrs_0.4.0           tzdb_0.2.0           
[67] polyclip_1.10-0       assertthat_0.2.1      xfun_0.30            
[70] e1071_1.7-9           class_7.3-20          viridisLite_0.4.0    
[73] tibble_3.1.6          units_0.8-0           ellipsis_0.3.2
```

Comment: Could you share some of the `csv` data or similar data that you used and your sessionInfo? Without the same data and sessionInfo, it's really difficult to reproduce the error that you got.

Comment: You might try uninstalling phantomjs and all dependencies via the linux command line and then install the {webshot} version with `webshot::install_phantomjs()` in the R terminal.

Comment: @the-mad-statter, That is a good suggestion. The problem seems to happen because of linux. With Mac and Windows there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install the `phantomjs` from the `webshot` package using the following code:

```
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

After that, you can run the following code which will output your table as `table.png`:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)

kable(csv) %>%                                                          
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F, htmltable_class = 'Liberation Sans') %>%
  kable_minimal() %>%
  save_kable(file = "table.png", bs_theme = "flatly", zoom = 1.5)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Please note that your table is really big.

Here is my `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 12.3.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] nl_NL.UTF-8/nl_NL.UTF-8/nl_NL.UTF-8/C/nl_NL.UTF-8/nl_NL.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] readxl_1.3.1       ggforce_0.3.3      dummies_1.5.6      plyr_1.8.6         magrittr_2.0.3     knitr_1.37        
 [7] kableExtra_1.3.4   terra_1.5-21       reshape_0.8.8      epitools_0.5-10.1  forcats_0.5.1      stringr_1.4.0     
[13] readr_2.1.2        tidyverse_1.3.1    DALEXtra_2.1.1     DALEX_2.4.0        mlbench_2.1-3      yardstick_0.0.9   
[19] workflowsets_0.1.0 workflows_0.2.4    tune_0.1.6         tidyr_1.2.0        tibble_3.1.6       rsample_0.1.1     
[25] recipes_0.2.0      purrr_0.3.4        parsnip_0.2.0      modeldata_0.1.1    infer_1.0.0        ggplot2_3.3.5     
[31] dplyr_1.0.8        dials_0.1.0        scales_1.1.1       broom_0.7.12       tidymodels_0.1.4   mapview_2.10.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] utf8_1.2.2           reticulate_1.24      tidyselect_1.1.2     htmlwidgets_1.5.4    grid_4.1.0           pROC_1.18.0         
  [7] munsell_0.5.0        codetools_0.2-18     units_0.8-0          future_1.24.0        withr_2.5.0          colorspace_2.0-3    
 [13] highr_0.9            uuid_1.0-4           rstudioapi_0.13      stats4_4.1.0         Rttf2pt1_1.3.8       listenv_0.8.0       
 [19] labeling_0.4.2       polyclip_1.10-0      plotROC_2.2.1        bit64_4.0.5          DiceDesign_1.9       farver_2.1.0        
 [25] rprojroot_2.0.2      parallelly_1.30.0    vctrs_0.4.0          generics_0.1.2       ipred_0.9-12         xfun_0.30           
 [31] R6_2.5.1             doParallel_1.0.17    ggiraph_0.8.2        flexmix_2.3-17       lhs_1.1.4            assertthat_0.2.1    
 [37] vroom_1.5.7          nnet_7.3-17          gtable_0.3.0         globals_0.14.0       processx_3.5.2       timeDate_3043.102   
 [43] rlang_1.0.2          systemfonts_1.0.4    modMax_1.1           splines_4.1.0        rgdal_1.5-28         extrafontdb_1.0     
 [49] lazyeval_0.2.2       ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2 yaml_2.3.5           reshape2_1.4.4       modelr_0.1.8         crosstalk_1.2.0     
 [55] backports_1.4.1      caret_6.0-90         extrafont_0.17       tools_4.1.0          lava_1.6.10          ellipsis_0.3.2      
 [61] raster_3.5-15        jquerylib_0.1.4      proxy_0.4-26         Rcpp_1.0.8.3         base64enc_0.1-3      progress_1.2.2      
 [67] classInt_0.4-3       ps_1.6.0             prettyunits_1.1.1    rpart_4.1.16         haven_2.4.3          fs_1.5.2            
 [73] here_1.0.1           leafem_0.1.6         furrr_0.2.3          magick_2.7.3         data.table_1.14.2    SparseM_1.81        
 [79] reprex_2.0.1         GPfit_1.0-8          hms_1.1.1            evaluate_0.15        leaflet_2.0.3.9000   compiler_4.1.0      
 [85] ingredients_2.2.0    KernSmooth_2.23-20   crayon_1.5.1         htmltools_0.5.2      tzdb_0.2.0           lubridate_1.8.0     
 [91] DBI_1.1.2            tweenr_1.0.2         dbplyr_2.1.1         MASS_7.3-55          sf_1.0-7             Matrix_1.4-0        
 [97] cli_3.2.0            parallel_4.1.0       gower_1.0.0          igraph_1.2.11        pkgconfig_2.0.3      sp_1.4-6            
[103] plotly_4.10.0        xml2_1.3.3           foreach_1.5.2        svglite_2.1.0        bslib_0.3.1          hardhat_0.2.0       
[109] webshot_0.5.2        prodlim_2019.11.13   rvest_1.0.2          callr_3.7.0          digest_0.6.29        rmarkdown_2.13      
[115] cellranger_1.1.0     kernlab_0.9-29       gtools_3.9.2         satellite_1.0.4      modeltools_0.2-23    lifecycle_1.0.1     
[121] nlme_3.1-155         jsonlite_1.8.0       viridisLite_0.4.0    fansi_1.0.3          pillar_1.7.0         lattice_0.20-45     
[127] fastmap_1.1.0        httr_1.4.2           survival_3.3-1       glue_1.6.2           png_0.1-7            iterators_1.0.14    
[133] bit_4.0.4            class_7.3-20         stringi_1.7.6        sass_0.4.1           e1071_1.7-9          future.apply_1.8.1
```

Comment: The error persist...may be I have to update some libraries in linux ?

Comment: @CésarArquero, could you please share your `sessioninfo`?

Comment: @CésarArquero, I shared my sessionInfo to and it doesn't seem like your packages are outdated. The error you get for installing the phantomjs is interesting. Maybe this post helps you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382789/qstandardpaths-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-defaulting-to-tmp-runtime-root-when

Comment: Thank you but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Maybe it is still a good idea to reinstall the important package like `kableExtra`. There have been some issues in the past like here: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/330

Comment: Didn't work...but thanks

Comment: @César Arquero, Maybe you should `install.packages("magick")` to let it work. One important thing is that `save_kable` and `as_image` provide really attractive feature, they may not work on every computer as mentioned on this post: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/save_kable_and_as_image.html. I would suggest to read that post and check if it works.

Comment: I tried to export from Windows and I get this: Could not load  c:%5CUsers%5Ccesar%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CTemp%5CRtmpE5CfIn%5C07a32f46b211b5d.html
Error in webshot::webshot(file_temp_html, file, ...) : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1